# How to fix [Delta RPMs disabled because /usr/bin/applydeltarpm not installed.] in installing deltarpm

Tags: linux, rpm

When I tried to install `deltarpm`

`sudo yum install deltarpm`

The following error returned.

`Delta RPMs disabled because /usr/bin/applydeltarpm not installed.`

How to fix them ?

I wonder applydeltarpm needs `deltarpm` so it was complicated.

If someone has opinion, please let me know

Thanks

Answer (score 7, accepted):

That’s not an error, it’s an informational message telling you that delta RPMs won’t be used (because the required tool isn’t installed).

It’s a chicken-and-egg situation: since you don’t have `applydeltarpm`, you can’t benefit from delta RPMs. In any case, since you’re installing a new package (`deltarpm` isn’t already installed on your system), `yum` wouldn’t use a delta RPM.

Once `deltarpm` is installed, future package upgrades will use delta RPMs if possible.

Answer (score 4):

I would highly recommend **avoiding** using deltaRPM unless you're the user of a 56Kbit/sec Internet connection.

DeltaRPM first unpacks the XZ archive inside the RPM package which is a relatively fast operation then it needs to apply a delta which is also relatively fast, but then it needs to compress it back which is quite slow even on the latest and greatest CPUs like Core i9 10900K or Ryzen 9 5900X.